# Проблема с программой в паскале, которая кодирует- декодирует текст

Tags: pascal

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я подвисла на какой то странной ситуации. Программу по кодировке и декодировке написала. Она работает - все ок. Текст кодируется, а вот с декодировкой что-то крайне странное и я вообще не могу понять как такое возможно.

Во первых: файл декодируется полностью кроме последних 3,5 строк. Как так?
Во- вторых: все файлы что я запускаю кодируются, а вот декодируются не все, только выборочно - что то да, что то нет. Если файл не декодируется - программа его создает но оставляет пустым. Почему?

Учитываю еще и тот факт, что я кодирую и декодирую один и тот же файл. В том смысле что сначала буру готовый - кодирую его в новом - пустом, декодирую в третьем - новом пустом. Потом сравниваю значения и - на тебе!

```
const Ckey=3;

function shifr(i:char):char;
   begin
   ord(I):=ord(i)+Ckey;
   if ord(i)>255 then ord(i):=ord(i)-255+32;
   shifr:=i;
   end;

function deshifr(i:char):char;
   begin
   ord(I):=ord(I)-Ckey;
   if ord(i)<32 then ord(i):=ord(i)+255-32;
   deshifr:=i;
   end;

procedure strshifr(var a1,b1:text);
   var x:integer; s:string;
   begin
   reset(a1);
   rewrite(b1);
   while (not EOF(a1)) do
      begin
      readln(a1,s);
         for x:=1 to length(s) do s[x]:=shifr(s[x]);
         writeln(b1,s);
      end;
   close(b1);
   end;

procedure strdeshifr(var b2,c2:text);
   var x:integer; s:string;
   begin
   reset(b2);
   rewrite(c2);
   while (not EOF(b2)) do
       begin
         readln(b2,s);
         For x:=1 to length(s) do s[x]:=deshifr(s[x]);
         writeln(c2,s);
       end;
   end;

var   a,b,c:text; x:integer; q:string;
begin
assign(a,'P_24_1.pas');
assign(b,'P_26_3.pas');
assign(c,'P_26_4.pas');
   writeln('Введите номер действия:1-шифровать, 2-дешифровать');
   readln(x);
case x of
1:q:='Программа шифрования запущена';
2:q:='Программа дешифрования запущена'
else q:='неверный номер действия'; end;
writeln(q);
   if x=1 then strshifr(a,b);
   if x=2 then strdeshifr(b,c);

close(a); close(b); close(c);
readln;
end.
```

Comment: @lioppo, все экстрасенсы в отпуске, а простые смертные посетители этого форума по фотографии дебажить не умеют. Приведите код вашей программы.

Comment: код в следующем вопросе. посмотрите, пожалуйста. здесь не хватает места

Comment: @lioppo барышня, вы пострадали от Бормана. Пардон, от Борланда. Сделать из симпатичного учебного языка паскаля такое угрёбище... 

Вероятная ошибка -- спотыкается на втором close(): первый close в процедуре, второй -- с третьей строке снизу. И в результате накрывается, не записав на диск хвост файла.

Ещё. Конструкция 

     ord(I):=ord(i)+Ckey;

ошибочна. Транслятор (кто у Вас -- delphi?) это жрёт, но вот писать код больше 255 в один символ программа всё равно не будет. Или меньше 0. Заведите целые переменные, и уже с ними упражняйтесь в арифметике. А в конце -- chr(эта_переменная).

Comment: @lioppo скорее даже не второе закрытие, а закрытие неоткрытого файла a при запуске программы декодирования.

Comment: @lioppo, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Comment: что за алгоритм шифрования? шифр Цезаря или что еще?

Comment: почему не используете побайтовое чтение? если посимвольно, то почему не используете готовый набор символов из алфавита?